# build failed when account changed

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths'.

> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
> > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s

firebase login:add
firebase login:list
firebase login:use
firebase projects:list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that there's a problem with the task :app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths, specifically with the property extraGeneratedResDir. Try to query the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) after task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.

Here are some of the additional things you can try-

1. Check all dependencies & updates in build.gradle file.
2. Ensure that your Firebase configuration files (google-services.json for Android) are correctly placed in your project directories.
3. Clean build and then re-build the file.